# How to FoldList over Dataset column without destroying/rebuilding Dataset?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have a `Dataset` in the following form but with many more rows and a few other columns.

```
SeedRandom[123];
ds = 
 Dataset[
  AssociationThread[{"Date", "R1","R2"}, 
      {DatePlus[DateObject@{2007, 12, 31}, {#, "EndOfMonth"}], 
       Sequence @@ RandomReal[{-0.5, 1}, 2]}
  ] & /@ Range[3]
 ]
```

[image]

I would like to apply `Rest@FoldList[#1 (1 + #2/100) &, 100, #] &` to columns `"R1"` and `"R2"` to get the following.

[image]

Currently I am destroying the dataset and then recreating it to get this result.

```
Dataset@MapThread[Append,
  {<|"Date" -> DatePlus[DateObject@{2007, 12, 31}, {#, "EndOfMonth"}]|> & /@ Range[3],
   Normal@ds[Rest@FoldList[#1 (1 + #2/100) &, 100, #] &, {"R1", "R2"}]}]
```

However, I would like not to have to do this because the columns that do not need to be folded need to be reincorporated into the result (e.g.`"Date"` in the example).  The `ds[All, {"R1" -> f, "R2" -> f}]` syntax operates on each column's row values individually.  Is there some similar syntax for folding a column?  Or a non destructive way of doing this?

Ideally I am looking to get the following but I can prepend the starting 100 value and date to the dataset if I can get the above.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't know if that's good enough:

```
fold = Rest@FoldList[#1 (1 + #2/100) &, 100, #] &;

ds[Transpose][{"R1" -> fold, "R2" -> fold}][Transpose]
```

[image]

Comment: This is reasonable. The dataset isn't so huge that the double `Transpose` will be a problem. +1 while we wait for other solutions.

Comment: @Edmund Do you possibly know why this is not working: `ds[Transpose@*Query[{"R1" -> fold, "R2" -> fold}]@*Transpose]`?

Comment: It seems correct syntax.  Odd that `ds[Query[{"R1" -> fold, "R2" -> fold}]@*Transpose][Transpose]` works and it doesn't.  Does it have something to do with ascending and descending operators?

Comment: @Edmund, as for your bonus: `Prepend[ds, AssociationThread[{"Date", "R1", "R2"} -> {DateObject@{2007, 12, 31}, 100., 100.}]]` works fine.

Comment: @Kuba The expression based upon `@*` does not work due to a limitation in the type inferencer.  The result of the first mapping query operator has type _Unknown_.  The second `Transpose` does not accept an unknown data type.  As usual, the operators work just fine if we take the type system out of the picture, e.g. `ds // Normal // Query[...]`.  In the alternate formulation in your response, the type _deducer_ (not _inferencer_) gets a chance to restore the missing type information enabling the second `Transpose` to function.  Oh, and +1.

Comment: This is probably the same thing in the end (but much wordier!) `ds[MapAt[fold,#,{{"R1"},{"R2"}}]&@*Merge[Identity]][Transpose]`